# Can not subdivide model in Blender 3.0.1

Tags: modeling

I want subdivide to be visible in object mode, like this: [image]

But when i right-click subdivide in edit mode, i get this in object mode. No subdivided model, just one piece:

[image]

EDIT: It worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: you either need to switch to wireframe view in object mode, set the object's maximum display type to wireframe, or add a wireframe modifier.

Comment: By the way, just for the sake of understanding and terminology, because you wrote "No subdivided model, just one piece": when you subdivide your model it get's a higher resolution, i.e. more vertices, edges, faces - that doesn't mean it gets split up in different pieces, so no matter if you see the wireframe in _Object Mode_ or not, it is still "just one piece" after subdividing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the wireframe in *Object* mode you either need to activate the option in the *Viewport Overlays* or in the *Viewport Display* panel:

[image]

[image]